# White-space: nowrap; css style not allowing for table to be responsive

Tags: html, css, html-table

So I'm trying to make a table with 3 columns where the second one has text and to prevent from it being too big for the screen I defined that it should be like the following:

```
max-width: 90%;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

And it works fine until I reduce the screen width to a value where the table tries to keep up with the text width when it shouldn't. While testing around in the browser I noticed that when I removed the `white-space: nowrap;` it allowed the table to resize to fit the screen but it made so the text doesn't have the `ellipsis` and appears all on the screen.

Here are some images of what is happening:

How it should be across all screen width:
[image: How it should be]

How it is when I decrease the screen width:
[image]

The code:

```css
table.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

table.table tr {
  height: 7em;
}

table.table tr td {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  padding: 10px;
}

table.table td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
}

table.table td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5em;
}

table.table td img {
  max-width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

table.table td p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #636262;
}

table.table td p:first-child {
  color: #1D1D25;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

table.table td p:last-child {
  font-size: 14px;
}

table.table td p span {
  color: #1D1D25;
}

table.table td:last-child a {
  color: #636262;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1040px) {
  .center-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .center-mobile .flex-self-center {
    padding-top: 7px;
  }
  .d-sm-none {
    display: none;
  }
  table.table td:first-child {
    width: 60px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child {
    width: 110px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child a {
    margin: 0 8px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .pageCount {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sign.desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .header .container-content .search-bar input {
    padding-left: 0;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .header .container-content .search-bar form {
    display: flex;
  }
  table.table {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
  }
  table.table td p:first-child {
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .desk tr td:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 10px;
  }
  .mob {
    display: none;
  }
  .mob td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mob td:last-child div:first-child {
    display: flex;
  }
  .mob td:last-child span {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  .mob td:last-child .states {
    right: 5px !important;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
    .desk {
      display: none;
    }
    .mob {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
  table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
  table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .table .actions {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -24px;
    right: 4px;
  }
  .table .actions a {
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .table .col1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .states {
    position: relative;
    right: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<table class="table mob">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img :src="https://s4.thcdn.com/productimg/960/960/11534151-1964670429319264.jpg" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="text-bold">Barra Proteica Light - 12 x 45g - Chocolate Branco e Framboesa</p>
        <p>From the Store: <span>Fnac</span></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col1 d-inline-block">
          <i v-if="x.price !== x.last_price" class="states fa fa-chevron-down text-success"></i>
          <span>10EUR</span>
        </div>
        <div class="actions d-inline-block">
          <a class="fas fa-sliders-h"></a>
          <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener nofollow" class="fa fa-link"></a>
          <a class="fa fa-times"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, what result do you want?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov for it to be responsive when I decrease the screen width

Comment: if you remove white-space: nowrap then you get your result

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov yes but the text doesn't overflow hidden

Comment: show the desired result on the screenshot, and I will help you

Comment: Under `table.table td p:first-child {
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }`

Comment: you can just remove white-space: nowrap; and it will show the desired output but with out the ellipses. @sergeykuznetsov

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Just noticed that the nowrap is also causing problems in other places

Comment: I have given a solution. Was it necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your task, it was important to specify the exact width ( `width: 50px` ) for the breakpoint, as well as the minimum width ( `min-width: 100%` ) for displaying the full text on a wide screen. This is how your selector should look like:

```
table.table td p:first-child {
    /*max-width: 90%;*/ /*delete this it*/
    width: 50px; /*add this it*/
    min-width: 100%; /*add this it*/
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```css
table.table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

table.table tr {
  height: 7em;
}

table.table tr td {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  padding: 10px;
}

table.table td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 128px;
}

table.table td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 1.5em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1.5em;
}

table.table td img {
  max-width: 80px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

table.table td p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #636262;
}

table.table td p:first-child {
  color: #1D1D25;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

table.table td p:last-child {
  font-size: 14px;
}

table.table td p span {
  color: #1D1D25;
}

table.table td:last-child a {
  color: #636262;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 1040px) {
  .center-mobile {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .center-mobile .flex-self-center {
    padding-top: 7px;
  }
  .d-sm-none {
    display: none;
  }
  table.table td:first-child {
    width: 60px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child {
    width: 110px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child a {
    margin: 0 8px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
  }
  .pageCount {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sign.desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .header .container-content .search-bar input {
    padding-left: 0;
    flex: 1;
  }
  .header .container-content .search-bar form {
    display: flex;
  }
  table.table {
    table-layout: fixed !important;
  }
  table.table td p:first-child {
    /*max-width: 90%;*/
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .desk tr td:nth-child(2) {
    max-width: 10px;
  }
  .mob {
    display: none;
  }
  .mob td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .mob td:last-child div:first-child {
    display: flex;
  }
  .mob td:last-child span {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
  }
  .mob td:last-child .states {
    right: 5px !important;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 1040px) {
    .desk {
      display: none;
    }
    .mob {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
  table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  table.table td:last-child .col1 i,
  table.table td:last-child .col1 span {
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .table .actions {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -24px;
    right: 4px;
  }
  .table .actions a {
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  .table .col1 {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
  .states {
    position: relative;
    right: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<table class="table mob">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img :src="https://s4.thcdn.com/productimg/960/960/11534151-1964670429319264.jpg" alt="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <p class="text-bold">Barra Proteica Light - 12 x 45g - Chocolate Branco e Framboesa</p>
        <p>From the Store: <span>Fnac</span></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="col1 d-inline-block">
          <i v-if="x.price !== x.last_price" class="states fa fa-chevron-down text-success"></i>
          <span>10EUR</span>
        </div>
        <div class="actions d-inline-block">
          <a class="fas fa-sliders-h"></a>
          <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener nofollow" class="fa fa-link"></a>
          <a class="fa fa-times"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```